# Insert 7500 million records from a microsoft azure DWH table to another table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to copy the contents of one table to another from a Microsoft azure dwh database table. This is done as a part of archival process. Basically we want only 2500 Million transactions in the table. The remaining 7500 million needs to be archived meaning it needs to be moved to another table.
Our idea is to copy 7500 million records to another table and then delete 7500 million records from the source table. The total number of columns is 360. We tried using the below query but seems it will take ages to complete.

```
select srpd.* into [Archive].[StagingxyzDetail_20220718]
from [dwh].[StagingxyzDetail] srpd
where fiscalmonth<202107
```

Comment: you can try to do it in the opposite way: move records you need(250 Mln.) to the new table and delete them from the old one

Comment: At a high-level, copy the relatively smaller 250m rows to a new table; Rename original table to the archived table name; Rename the new table to original table; delete 250m rows from archived table.

Comment: The existing table has dependency with many reports and stored procedures. Yesterday we copied 40 million data with the help of the query given in my question. That took almost 1 day and when it is 250 Million , I think it takes many days or crash in between.

Comment: You can use grouping and transfer one million records at a time. You can do this with a While loop.

Comment: You've tagged azure-sql-data-warehouse (now called Synapse). It should perform fine with this number of records. Likewise there are a lot of recommendations to move data to blob and use CTAS for fast data loads. Or is this actually a data warehouse schema inside a standard azure sql?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This is not a data warehouse schema inside standard azure SQL. The table resides in a azure data warehouse database. can you point out some examples of recommendations that you have mentioned. we are using this database since last 6 years.

Comment: Try `from [dwh].[StagingxyzDetail] srpd with (tablock)`

Comment: Just going back a step, why are you "archiving" the records? For performance reasons? SQL DW is built to easily accomodate this number of records (unless you don't want to pay for it) but you need to have table design right, i.e. hashed distribution on a suitable key, clustered columnstore storage, partitioning, non clustered indexes. But if you still want to archive 750k records into another table, the quickest way to load a table is with CTAS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas

Comment: CTAS is good for fast creation of a table, butyou also need to have the source indexed correctly so it can find fiscalmonth<202107 quickly. For example you need a hash distribution that spreads all fiscalmonths evenly across all nodes, then you need non clustered indexes or partitioning on fiscalmonth. There are a lot of design considerations required to use this expensive tool properly

Comment: When considering performance on Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools, you must always consider at least four things: DWU, the resource class associated with the user running the query, table geometry (distribution and indexing) and concurrency.  Please add that information to your question.  Partitioning is also supported so a partition switching by year pattern might help here.